# JTextpane set caret position without changing scrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextpane, caret

I have Jtextpane added to scroll pane and i use the following code,

```
textPanel.setCaretPosition(5);
JScrollBar sb = scroll.getVerticalScrollBar();
sb.setValue( sb.getMaximum());
```

The contents of jtextpane is simple 10 "\n" characters. The above piece of code i use to set caret position at some place keeping scroll bar at bottom. if i remove setCaretPosition i can able to set scroll position at bottom but with that code its always going to top.

Note : caret property is ALWAYS_UPDATE .

Is it possible to achieve this?

Please help

Comment: scroll bars work with the caret positions. why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Sanjeev even if the scrollbar is at bottom the caret position is visible. There is a need to hide the lines above the caret position.

Comment: You can try setting caret position to last character and then move it to the middle. this shall do the trick.

Comment: @madhu, not everybody has read your 5 previous question related to this topic so they don't know the context of what you are trying to do. So, post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates what is happening and then explain how you want it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the methods

```
public CaretListener[] getCaretListeners()
public void addCaretListener(CaretListener listener)
public void removeCaretListener(CaretListener listener)
```

Before setting caret to position get all the caret listeners, remove them, set your caret position and readd them back.